# Spring BatchSqlUpdate vs NamedParameterJdbcTemplate using named parameters

Tags: spring, jdbc, sql-update, batch-processing

I have been using the `BatchSqlUpdate` class successfully for a while. The only annoyance using it is that named parameters need to be registered before running any query using the `declareParameter` or `setParameter` methods. This means that the type of the parameters has to be declared as well. However, Spring also provides a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` class which has a very convenient `batchUpdate` method that takes named parameters as input (an array of maps or `SqlParameterSource` objects) **without the need of declaring them first**. On top of that, this class can be reused easily and I also believe it's thread-safe.
So I have a couple of questions about this:

- What's the recommended way to perform (multiple) batch updates?
- Why is this feature duplicated across two different classes that also behave differently?
- Why does `BatchSqlUpdate` require declared parameters if `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` does not?

Thanks for the thoughts!

Giovanni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research, I reached the following conclusions.

First of all, I realized that the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` class is the only one accepting named parameters for batch updates. The method `batchUpdate(String sql,Map[] batchValues)` was added in Spring 3 to achieve this.

The `BatchSqlUpdate` class contains an overridden `update(Object... params)` method that *adds the given statement parameters to the queue rather than executing them immediately*, as stated in the javadoc. This means that the statements will be executed only when the `flush()` method is called or the batch size exceeded the maximum. This classed doesn't support named parameters, although it contains a `updateByNamedParam()` method inherited from `SqlUpdate`. This is unfortunate since this method allows reuse of the same map for the named parameters, whereas the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate()` method requires an array of maps, with the associated overhead, code bloating and complications in reusing the array of maps if the batch size is variable.

I think it would be useful to have an overridden version of `updateByNamedParam(Map paramMap)` in `BatchSqlUpdate` to behave just like `update(Object... params)` but with added support for named parameters.